# ionic display chartjs data from json http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, chart.js

I'm building an ionic app to display dashboard (pie chart) by retrieving the data from URL/HTTP request. Here is my code in `.ts` file calling data from the url and I managed to display this in a table form using `e.g. {{ items.data }}` in `.html` file:

```
public items : Array<any> = [];

ionViewWillEnter() : void{
      this.load();
   }

 load() : void{
          this.http.get('http://localhost/test/retrieve-data.php')
          .subscribe((data : any) =>{
             console.dir(data);
             this.items = data;
          },
          (error : any) =>{
             console.dir(error);
          });
       }
```

My problem here is I want to retrieve data from ONE row and display it in pie chart. For example, this is that one row that I wanna fetch:

```
[{"id":9,"twitter_name":"Max Payne","positive_tweets":24,"negative_tweets":14,"total_tweets":38,"pos_percent":63,"neg_percent":37}]
```

I want to display a pie chart that shows values of `pos_percent` and `neg_percent`.

Here is what I've been doing and still stuck on calling the row data:

```
@ViewChild('pieChart') pieChart;

public pieChartEl : any;

createPieChart()
   {

      this.pieChartEl           = new Chart(this.pieChart.nativeElement,
      {
         type: 'pie',
         data: {
             labels: ["Positive","Negative"],
             datasets: [{
                 data                  : [],
                 duration              : 2000,
                 easing                : 'easeInQuart',
                 backgroundColor       : "rgba(54, 116, 152, 0.5)",
                 hoverBackgroundColor  : "rgba(160, 116, 152, 0.5)"
             }]
         },
         options : {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            layout: {
               padding: {
                  left     : 50,
                  right    : 0,
                  top      : 0,
                  bottom   : 0
               }
            },
            animation: {
               duration : 5000
            }
         }
      });



      this.chartLoadingEl = this.pieChartEl.generateLegend();
   }

ionViewDidLoad()
   {
      this.createPieChart();
   }
```

How do I fetch that data?

Answer (score 2):

To draw PieChart with from HTTP request, Please follow my instruction below:

1- Make sure you install Angular 2 charts and Charts.js, simply type this command:

```
npm install ng2-charts --save
npm install chart.js --save
```

2- Register ChartsModule:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    ChartsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

3- Add Canvas tag to your html file like below:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Welcome to Ionic!</h2>

  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas baseChart #baseChart="base-chart"
                [data]="doughnutChartData"
                [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                [chartType]="doughnutChartType"></canvas>
  </div>

</ion-content>
```

4: Get json data and draw to canvas:

**Note:** I load json from asset/datas.json via HTTP.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild("baseChart") pieChartEl: BaseChartDirective;

  public doughnutChartLabels: string[] = [];
  public doughnutChartData: number[] = [];
  public doughnutChartType: string = 'doughnut';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.updateData();
  }

  public updateData() {
    this.http.get("/assets/datas.json").subscribe((res: Response) => {
          let jsons = res.json();
          let data = jsons[0];
          this.doughnutChartLabels.push("pos_percent");
          this.doughnutChartLabels.push("neg_percent");

          this.doughnutChartData.push(data.pos_percent);
          this.doughnutChartData.push(data.neg_percent);

          console.log(this.doughnutChartLabels);
          console.log(this.doughnutChartData);

          if(this.pieChartEl !== undefined){
            this.pieChartEl.ngOnDestroy();
            this.pieChartEl.chart = this.pieChartEl.getChartBuilder(this.pieChartEl.ctx);
          }
      });
  }
}
```

5: This is my result:

[image]

You can check my code in [ionic3-chart](https://github.com/ManKeomorakort/ionic3-benchmark/tree/master/ionic3-chart)
I hope this could help :).

Comment: Im trying to to make charts for every row. For example this is my data from phpmyadmin https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl68n.png . So there's four users and im trying to make pie chart for every user (four charts) based on their positive and negative tweet values.

Comment: Great Explaination bong!

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
export class YourClass {
   data; //Array of values

   constructor() { }

   ionViewDidLoad() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/test/retrieve-data.php",true);
    xhr.onreadystatechnage = function() {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) //The JSON from your php server
      //configure your Json to an array (for the chart.js labels)
      this.data = //your configured json to array -> in Array 
      this.drawChart();
    } 

     xhr.send(null);


   }

   drawChart() {
    this.pieChartEl           = new Chart(this.pieChart.nativeElement,
      {
         type: 'pie',
         data: {
             labels: ["Positive","Negative"],
             datasets: [{
                 data                  : this.data, //here your data
                 duration              : 2000,
                 easing                : 'easeInQuart',
                 backgroundColor       : "rgba(54, 116, 152, 0.5)",
                 hoverBackgroundColor  : "rgba(160, 116, 152, 0.5)"
             }]
         },
         options : {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            layout: {
               padding: {
                  left     : 50,
                  right    : 0,
                  top      : 0,
                  bottom   : 0
               }
            },
            animation: {
               duration : 5000
            }
         }
      });



      this.chartLoadingEl = this.pieChartEl.generateLegend();

   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but nothing popped out. There are numbers of rows in my data and how do i fetch that row specifically.

Comment: Now I understand what you want to split the labels from the data... so therefore you should loop through the JSON (its key-value paired) and in your loop you can add the keys to the label array and and the values to the data array

Comment: Can you show me an example. Im sorry im new to this